# kendo grid in kendo tabs using partial view

Tags: c#, razor, entity-framework-4, kendo-ui

For some reason i can get second tab (Product Details) to bind record in the grids although the GetAllProductList return records. Please advise, thank you

**index.cshtml**
HOME/Index.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("tabstrip")
    .Items(items =>
    {
        items.Add().Text("Search")
            .LoadContentFrom("Index", "ProductDetails")
            .Selected(true);



        items.Add().Text("Product Details")
       .LoadContentFrom("_ProductData", "ProductDetails")



    })
)
```

**ProductDetails/Index.cshtml**

@(Html.Kendo().Grid()

```
        .Name("BookGrid")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "align:center; font-size:10px; width:950px" })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {

            columns.Bound(p => p.BookId).Width(95);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(120);


        })

        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Sortable()
            //.Pageable()
        .Pageable(paging => paging
            .Input(false)
            .Numeric(true)

            .PreviousNext(true)
            .PageSizes(new int[] { 5, 10, 25, 50 })
            .Refresh(false)

        )
        .Selectable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ColumnMenu(c => c.Columns(false))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

            .Ajax()//bind with Ajax instead server bind
            .PageSize(10)
            .ServerOperation(true)
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.BookId);

                })
                                     .Sort(sort => sort
                                  .Add(x => x.Name).Descending())

                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetBookData", "ProductDetails").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))


            )



    )
```

**ProductDetails/_ProductData.chtml (Partial page)**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<HH.PrductModel>()

        .Name("ProductGrid")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "align:center; font-size:10px; width:950px" })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {

            columns.Bound(p => p.ProductId).Width(95);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(120);


        })

        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Sortable()
            //.Pageable()
        .Pageable(paging => paging
            .Input(false)
            .Numeric(true)

            .PreviousNext(true)
            .PageSizes(new int[] { 5, 10, 25, 50 })
            .Refresh(false)

        )
        .Selectable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ColumnMenu(c => c.Columns(false))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

            .Ajax()//bind with Ajax instead server bind
            .PageSize(10)
            .ServerOperation(true)
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.ProductId);

                })
                                     .Sort(sort => sort
                                  .Add(x => x.Name).Descending())

                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetProductData", "ProductDetails").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))


            )



    )

**ProductDetailscontroller**

public ActionResult Index()

{ 
   return View();
} 

///Display for tab 1
public ActionResult GetBookData ([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            return Json(GetAllBookList().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

 private static IEnumerable<BookModel> GetAllBookList()
        {
            using (var dc = new HHEntities())
            {
                var result = (from a in dc.Books

                              select new BookModel
                              {
                                  BookId= a.BookId,
                                  Name= a.Name



                              });
                return result.Distinct().ToList();
            }


        }


///Display for tab 2

public ActionResult GetProductData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            return Json(GetAllProductList().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The following will return records but for some reason it would bind to grid in Product details tab

```
       /// <summary>

        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static IEnumerable<ProductModel> GetAllProductList()
        {
            using (var dc = new HHEntities())
            {
                var result = (from a in dc.Products

                              select new ProductModel
                              {
                                  ProductId= a.ProductId,
                                  Name= a.Name,
                                  Description= a.Description,
                                  ExpiryDate= a.ExpiryDate


                              });
                return result.Distinct().ToList();
            }


        }

    public ActionResult __ProductData()
  { return PartialView();}
```

Comment: What is the problem again? You say that you can bind the grid.

Comment: it is just showing empty grid. It really weird. even when i checked the var result from GetAllProductList it showing records. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that both grids are rendered with the same HTML id attribute (which is set via the `Name()` method). You need to give your grids unique names. For example you can put some index in `ViewData` in the action methods which render the partial view that contains the grid. Then use that index in the partial view itself to make the grid name unique:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<HH.PrductModel>()
      .Name("Product" + ViewData["index"])
```

Comment: Hi Atanas, i have modified the code. Would you kindly advise. thank you

Comment: I don't see your code changing the Name() of the grid. Try that. Also why is the first tab loading a full page instead of a partial view?